# R: How to create a basic x,y plot (2 vars) with repeated points having a different color (~heatmap)

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

This plot:
plot(Data$grade, Data$absences)
produces the plot I need, except I need to be able to identify the repeated values.

Absences ranges from 0 to 19.  Grade ranges from 0 to 10 (integers).
There are 320 students.

For example, a grade of 7 with absences of 0 has 84 repeats.

I would like a scaled heat map, where the color of a point starts at light blue (1 data point) and scales up to dark blue (>70), with 7 steps. (Approximately.) Heat mapped points of different colors could also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a specific function to build a heatmap, but you can count the number of unique rows in your df (with `dplyr`) and use that count as the `alpha` (transparency) parameter on ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame( # Creating some dummy data
  Grades = sample(0:10, 10000, TRUE),
  Abscences = sample(0:19, 10000, TRUE)) 

df = df %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(COUNT = n())

ggplot(df, aes(y=Grades, x=Abscences, alpha=COUNT)) +
  geom_point(color="darkblue", size=5, shape="square")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That's working.

Comment: Did some research and found that `geom_tile` is better. Try `ggplot(df, aes(y=Grades, x=Abscences, fill=COUNT)) +  geom_tile()`

Comment: I like your original version better.  I want a plot, with independent points, which is what that give me.  Thanks.